# PHP extract word that contains special character from a string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string :

```
$str = " Côte-d'azure ! (3000) limousin - limousine  ";
```

And I need to extract some words and put them in an array. to get finally :

```
array (
        0 => "Côte-d'azure",
        1 => "limousin",
        2 => "limousine"
     );
```

So I tried :

```
preg_match_all("/[a-zA-Z]+/", $str, $all);
```

but this ignore the special character **ô** , **'**  and **-**

please any advise ?

Comment: Just a quick guess: try the [character property](www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php): `/\p{L}[\p{L}-]+/u` (the character class is to allow hyphens later on in the word)

Comment: Thank you m.buettner, but it still ignore the single quote

Comment: Right, I overlooked that. That's what the character class is for. Let me make it an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Unicode mode `u` and [character properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php):

```
preg_match_all('/\p{L}[\p{L}\\\\\'-]+/u', mysql_real_escape_string($str), $all);
```

This requires one (Unicode) letter and then matches as many other Unicode letters, backslashes, hyphens and apostrophes as possible. If you want other punctuation characters to not separate a word, include it in the character class.

Note that 5 backslashes. Three backslashes are removed when the string is compiled, because two of them escape the backslash following them, and the last one escapes the `'`. So the regex engine receives only 2 backslashes. These are interpreted by the regex engine as one literal backslash. Unfortunately there is no way to use less than 4 backslashes to represent one literal backslash when using PHP.

Comment: Please I still have the problem with the single quote. thanks a lot m.buettner

Comment: @SamiElHilali it works perfectly for me. Could you show how you tried to use the regex?

Comment: preg_match_all("/\b[\p{L}'-]+|[a-z]+\b/u", $str, $all); where 

$str = mysql_real_escape_string($str);

Comment: Wellthat is important. [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) prepends `'` with a backslash. This should then probably be included in the character class. Also, your regex has some other issues. I will edit mine to accommodate for the backslash, and then you should use my version, I think.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', $your_string, $matches))
{
  echo '  symbol encountered !!';
}
```